# Unequal integrals and proving the validity of a sum involving the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I was working with the family of integrals given by:

$$ S(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{e^x-1} dx$$

It is relatively easy to establish an expression for $S(a)$. As usual, we define its cosine variant and use Euler's formula.

$$ C(a) + iS(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{e^x-1}dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{iax}\cdot e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}dx = \int_0^{\infty} {e^{-(1-ia)x}} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-nx} dx $$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-((n+1)-ia)x} dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1) + ia}{(n+1)^2+a^2}$$

Thus,

$$ S(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a}{a^2+(n+1)^2} = \frac{\pi a \coth(\pi a) - 1}{2a}$$

Then

$$\int_0^1 S(a)da = \int_0^1 \frac{\pi a \coth(\pi a) - 1}{2a} da$$

Which is

$$\int_0^1 S(a)da = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \ln(\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}) = 0.650923....$$

But if I compute the integral over the summation formula, I get:

$$ \int_0^1 S(a)da = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a}{a^2+(n+1)^2} da$$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{a da}{a^2+(n+1)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln \big(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\big) $$

Which, [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summation+n+%3D+0+to+inf+1%2F2*ln%281%2B%281%2F%28n%2B1%29%5E2%29%29), is equal to $0.648442....$

Which is weird, because if you apply the Taylor Series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ in the expression obtained and rewrite the sum, we get an interesting sum:

$$ S = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\cdot \zeta(2n)$$

Which WolframAlpha calculates to be $0.650923$....

Can someone explain why the values obtained are different?

Also, is it correct to assert the equality

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\cdot \zeta(2n) = \ln(\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi})$$

I am very much interested if there are any other methods to compute the sum in the LHS, so as to verify the veracity of the proposed equality independently.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analytical method is correct, and all of your calculations are correct.  The only issue is Wolfram Alpha's evaluation of the sum, which is incorrect.  Using *Mathematica* (version 13.3):

```
NSum[Log[1 + 1/(n + 1)^2]/2, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

returns $0.650923$.  Since this is an issue with computer evaluation, there is nothing else to say, except to stress that computers can be wrong, and that it is important to verify the results they provide.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Can you also confirm the sum that arises from the equality, added in the recent edit?

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus Yes, your identity $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \zeta(2n) = \log \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}$$ is true.

Comment: @ScipioAemilianus I used my very old version of Mathematica (version still in the single digits!) and even it gave the correct answer of $0.650923$. You'd assume Wolfram employs the same algorithms as Mathematica. So it might be a good idea to post a question to Mathematica StackExchange so they will be aware of the bug in Wolfram.